# Encode content inside xml element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

There is an XML tag with many special characters and new lines. I want to transform it to JSON format using XSL. I did it using **replace** function. Is there a way to do the same functionality using separate functionality like encoding content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tyring I could find the solution.

**encode-for-uri** can be used for that.

https://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/fn/encode-for-uri.html